# Vagrant networking error when following docs

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm getting this error:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* An IP is required for a private network.
```

when I follow this documentation: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html and specify that I want DHCP to assign the IP address like so:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
```

Anyone know how to get this working?

**EDIT:**

I have also just tried:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, type: :dhcp
```

which works and assigns an IP address of `10.0.2.15`, but I don't understand this as my DHCP server assigns addresses in the `192.168.1.x` range? Does this stuff actually ever work for anyone?

Comment: By "my DHCP server" you mean an external one or the VirtualBox host-only adapter? If you need an ip address from an external dhcp you have to use a public network instead of a private one.

Comment: Hi @Emyl, I meant the DHCP server on my router. If it's the case that I need a public network, can you tell me why the docs say I can set the type as dhcp for a private one? How does that work then?

Comment: Private network is mapped to VirtualBox host-only network, so if you choose it you get an ip address from the VBox's internal dhcp server. Indeed, that's the easiest way to create a private network, that's the reason why it's mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Vagrant box to pull from the same DHCP your host box does, use this line in your Vagrantfile:

`config.vm.network :public_network, :auto_config => true`

This corresponds to a VBox bridged network, which it sounds like you want.

**edit**: added the auto_config bit. It should ask you which adapter you want to use when it boots; you can also specify `:bridge => "en1"` (or whatever your adapter happens to be named; en1 is my Macbook's USB ethernet) on that line to hard-code a host adapter name.

Comment: Cheers, but when I do this, it hangs for about 10 minutes and then doesn't configure the network card with an IP address.

Comment: I added some more information to my original; I ran into that once but I thought it was just my DHCP server being ornery, so I didn't include the extra info. See if that helps now.